# Jump to specific field when a multiple choice radio button is selected in Gravity Forms

Tags: html, radio-button, gravity-forms-plugin, radiobuttonlist, gravityforms

is there an option or maybe a small custom code to make Gravity Forms radio buttons jump to a field on selection?

In my example, i have a list of 14 options. Using a condition logic when you select one option a custom HTML is revealed right under each and every option. For desktop is super ok, the screen is big and all fit well. The problem is for mobile devices because you select an option but after that, you have to scroll to see the custom HTML.

Is there any option or custom code snippet in Gravity Forms that jumps to that custom HTML when an option is selected?

I found some resources on how to make this using HTML code with ids but this is somehow dynamic though the HTML code is placed in the same position. My first idea was to add the same ID to each and every  HTML code so that when a radio button is pressed it scrolls to that ID. Don't know if it makes sense but ...

Can someone help me with some resources or give me some hints? Many thanks.

Comment: This seems like a very weird interaction pattern and I doubt that Gravit Forms enables you to do that. You’d probably create quite some usability issues instead of solving a scroll issue. Generally, if content gets added, it should be added *after* the trigger. Scrolling, then, is no issue, since the user will scroll to continue any way.

Comment: Andy you may be right. Imagine just your ordinary phone apps. You make a choice then the screen has an animation and you then see your other options. This is just a common interaction and behaviour in our days. I don't see your point. In fact, a user friendly form should do this imo.